# Como mostrar próximo campo quando usuário clicar no botão verde

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, css3

Tenho vários campos que estão escondidos e só devem aparecer quando o usuário clicar no botão ver ao lado do primeiro campo.

A minha ideia inicial seria quando a pessoa clicar no botão verde (after do .newField) ele adicionasse a classe newField ao próximo campo.

(não tem problema se o botão verde ficar duplicado, é claro que se conseguirem deixar só no último é melhor.)

```css
.c-form .hide {
  display: none;
}

.newField {
  display: block!important;
  position: relative;
}

.c-form .newField:after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f138";
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #1fa050
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="c-form">
  <form id="formsugestoes" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h3>Fale conosco</h3>
    <input type="hidden" name="setor" value="">

    <input type="hidden" name="assunto" value="formsugestoes">

    <label class="lado hide newField"><span>Nome: *</span><input class="text" type="text" name="nome" value="" required></label>

    <label class="lado hide"><span>E-mail: *</span><input class="text" type="email" name="email" value="" required></label>

    <label class="lado hide"><span>Cidade: *</span><input class="text" type="text" name="cidade" value="" required></label>

    <label class="lado hide"><span>Telefone:</span><input class="text mask-tel" type="text" name="telefone" value="" required></label>

    <label class="lado hide"><span>Mensagem:</span><textarea class="text" name="mensagem" value=""> </textarea></label>

    <div><input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" class="btnEnviar hide lado" /></div>

  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: No click basta validar as condições pra identificar os campos que não ser exibidos e remover deles a classe "hide", e setar o focus no "próximo" campo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está criando um *pseudo-elemento* no `label`, assim não tem como detectar via JavaScript o clique exato no botão, o clique vai ficar ativo no `label` por inteiro, o que tira a intenção do clique no botão. Até porque se clicar no botão vai focar o campo do nome, o que não faz sentido.

Sugiro que crie o botão em um `span` fora do `label` para que fique independente, desta forma você pode capturar o clique apenas no botão sem focar o campo. E também ir clonando o botão e adicionando após o próximo `label` até chegar no botão <kbd>Enviar</kbd>.

**Ficaria assim:**

```js
$(document).on("click", "span.newField", function(){
   var clone = $(this).clone();
   var next = $(this).next();

   $(this)
   .prev()
   .removeClass("newField hide");

   if(next[0].tagName != "DIV"){
      $(this)
      .next()
      .addClass("newField")
      .removeClass("hide")
      .after(clone);
   }else{
      $(this)
      .next()
      .find("input")
      .removeClass("hide");
   }

   $(this).remove();
});
```

```css
.c-form .hide {
  display: none;
}

.newField {
  display: inline-block!important;
  position: relative;
}

.c-form span.newField:after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f138";
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #1fa050;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="c-form">
  <form id="formsugestoes" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h3>Fale conosco</h3>
    <input type="hidden" name="setor" value="">

    <input type="hidden" name="assunto" value="formsugestoes">

    <label class="lado hide newField"><span>Nome: *</span><input class="text" type="text" name="nome" value="" required></label>
    <span class="newField"></span>

    <label class="lado hide"><span>E-mail: *</span><input class="text" type="email" name="email" value="" required></label>

    <label class="lado hide"><span>Cidade: *</span><input class="text" type="text" name="cidade" value="" required></label>

    <label class="lado hide"><span>Telefone:</span><input class="text mask-tel" type="text" name="telefone" value="" required></label>

    <label class="lado hide"><span>Mensagem:</span><textarea class="text" name="mensagem" value=""> </textarea></label>

    <div><input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" class="btnEnviar hide lado" /></div>

  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você faz um listener do botão, e via javascript remove a class ".hide".

```
<script>
    $('.botao_ver').click(function(){
        $(this).children('.lado').removeClass('hide');
    });
</script>
```

Essa função é genérica, dentro do seu código não consegui identificar qual botão você vai clicar para mostrar os inputs, mas para ter uma base, isso deve lhe ajudar.

Comment: O btn na verdade é um pseudo-elemento ::after na label... é um elemento construido no CSS ele só aparece depois que a página renderiza pois ele não está no html

Comment: Exatamente, e por este motivo não consegui fazer funcionar.